# How to change the encoding of a file created by SQL Server Agent job to UTF-8?

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, utf-8, sql-server-agent

I'm trying to create a daily job to query items inventory of my SAP db (SQL Server 17), save the results in a .txt file, and ftp it to my website server, where I'll parse it using PHP, and use it to update stock level on the MySQL db of the website.

I created a job on sql server agent, that will run the following query:

```
SELECT
Cast (ItemCode as varchar(20)) + '##'+
Cast (OnHand as  varchar(20))+ '@@' AS Item_Stock 
FROM OITW
WHERE OITW.WhsCode='01' AND OnHand>0
```

The result is outputted to a .txt file like so: [image: output file setup]

All of the above is working well.

The problem is that the file isn't saved as UTF-8, so after it is uploaded to the server (via ftp), any type of PHP parsing (explode, substr etc) fails.

**So what I'm looking for** is a way to force the txt file to be saved as UTF-8, or a way to make PHP read the file and be able to parse it as string.

I should add that both fields: OnHand and ItemCode, are numeric. OnHand is inventory field, so obviously only numbers. ItemCode may contain some non-ASCII characters, but if there are such items they are irrelevant anyway; I'm saying it to emphasize there's no fear of data loss in converting encoding, since numbers are numbers in any encoding (I think...).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, is the simple answer.

The more verbose answer would be to add a further step in your job that runs a Powershell script that does. Something like this should work:

```
$Path = "C:\{the rest of the file path in your image}\office_stock.txt"
$Content = Get-Content -Path $Path
Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $Content -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Thanks! 
But the second step you suggested fails, with the following error message:
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. A job step received an error at line 3 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $Content -Encode UTF8'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Encode'.  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.

Comment: Apologies, @einav, should have been `-Encoding`. Have edited the post.

Comment: I sure hope not! it's a new server that was installed yesterday...
5.1.17763.771

Comment: OK. will try again and let you know

Comment: Yay! it's working now. Funny how you started the answer with "you can't", and then gave the solution of how I can :-)

Comment: My comment on "You can't" is true, in the sense that you can't have SQL Server generate a UTF-8 file, @einav . Agent will still create a UTF-16 file. What this does is just takes all that content, and then rewrites it in UTF-8.